# Update values in one list with values from another

Tags: python

I have the following code which updates values in a list (rsp.rsp_list) with new values from a much smaller list (cmd.cmd_list). How can I do the following in a more pythonic way?

```
   for i in rsp.rsp_list:
        for j in cmd.cmd_list.data:
            if i.common.id == j.id:
                i.common.value.CopyFrom(j.val)
```

Comment: What type have i and j ?

Comment: you can find similar items like this:

      for i in set(a).intersection(b): print i

Comment: could you redefine `rsp.rsp_list` and `cmd.cmd_list.data` as dictionaries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical tradeof between memory and execution time:

```
cmd_data = {cmd.id: cmd.value for cmd in cmd.cmd_list}
for rsp in rsp.rsp_list:
    if rsp.common.id in cmd_data:
        rsp.common.value.CopyFrom(cmd_data[rsp.common.id])
```

Comment: Two comments: 1) this will raise a `KeyError` if `rsp.common.id` is not present in `cmd_data`.  You should probably do `if rsp.common.id in cmd_data:`. 2) No need to use a list comprehension when creating the dictionary, if you leave out the square brackets, it will become a generator expression, and have the same result.

Comment: Completely agree with your comments, will update the snippet.

Comment: A try except would speed up execution time more.